# Lower bound on arc length in the plane

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I am looking at arc length of a continuous differentiable function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Such that the arc length is $L = \int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$. Where the derivative of $f$ is $f' =\frac{dy}{dx}$.

When I think of the triangle inequality, the idea of the shortest distance between two points is the line in between them. So naturally I came up with
$$|b-a| \leq \int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$$
Is this bound true? I would think if it is, you would most likely using the triangle inequality to prove it.

Edit: So after the answer from below here is the rough outline of the proof (so that it is all contained within the question)

$0 \leq x^2$

$0 \leq(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$

$1 \leq 1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$

$1 \leq \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$

$\int^{b}_{a} 1 dx \leq \int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$

$ |b-a| \leq \int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arc length is a non-negative real number (and the distance between two points cannot be negative), so the above is indeed true for $b\geq a$.

Since $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2\geq 0$ we have that $$ \int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx\geq\int_{a}^{b}1dx=b-a.$$